# Creating a sliding timeline with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, slide

I am attempting to create a simple sliding timeline with a button. In other words, when I click the arrow button, I would like one DIV to slide out and another to slide in its place. Is the code I have written on the right track or should I look at a different route?

Here is the code that I have written thus far:

HTML:

```
<section id="b2bTimeline" class="center">

<div id="arrows">
        <div id="tabOne">
            <a href="#" class="activeTab"><img src="arrowRight.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div id="tabTwo">
            <a href="#" class="activeTab"><img src="arrowLeft.png" /></a>
        </div>
   </div>

   <div class="cBoth"></div>

    <div id="timelineListOne">
        <div id="five">
            <h4>2005</h4>
            <h5>our first client.</h5>
            <h6>06/2005</h6>
            <p></p>
        </div>

        <div id="seven">
            <h4>2007</h4>
            <h5>we go full-time.</h5>
            <h6>06/2007</h6>
            <p></p>
        </div>

        <div id="eightA">
            <h4>2008</h4>
            <h5>we go mobile.</h5>
            <h6>07/2008</h6>
            <p></p>
       </div>              
   </div>

   <div id="timelineListTwo">
        <div id="eightB">
        <h4>2008</h4>
        <h5>we incorporate.</h5>
        <h6>11/2008</h6>
            <p></p>
  </div>

  <div id="ten">
        <h4>2010</h4>
        <h5>we expand.</h5>
        <h6>06/2010</h6>
            <p></p>
   </div>

   <div id="twelve">   
        <h4>2012</h4>
            <h5>game changers.</h5>
            <h6>06/2012</h6>
                <p></p> 
    </div>
</div>

   <div id="timelineListThree">
        <div id="thirteen">
            <h4>2013</h4>
            <h5>facelift & future.</h5>
            <h6>06/2013</h6>
                <p></p>
        </div>
   </div>

</section>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#tabOne").click(function(){
var slide = ('#timelineListOne', '#timelineListTwo', '#timelineListThree')
    $('slide').each(function(){
            $(this).animate({marginLeft:'-1200px'}, 'slow', function(){
    $(this).animate({marginLeft: '-50px'}, 'slow');
});
```

Hope this question is clear enough. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Not clear..you forgot to ask a question.Have you run the code and saw ??

Comment: I have run the code and nothing happens.

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle?  http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jquery code has many problems in it ..replace it with the code below ..it will work

```
$("#tabOne").click(function(){
    var slide = new Array('#timelineListOne', '#timelineListTwo', '#timelineListThree');
    $(slide).each(function(key, value){
          $(value).animate({marginLeft:'-1200px'}, 'slow', function(){
              $(value).animate({marginLeft: '-50px'}, 'slow');
          });
    });
});
```